# Zend Framework Queries on Mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am working with zend framework and I am new to it.
The Site which is built has lots of transactions to/from mysql and there are lots of errors.
Is there any way to understand the queries which are made by Zend Framework?
If i could see them , I could easily change correct them but unfortunatly I didnt find how to do that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries  in ZF are instance of Zend_Db_Select , simply

```
$query = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select()->from('user')->where('id = ?',1);
```

To see its sql representation simply do

```
echo $query ; 

or 

echo $query->__toString();
```

Comment: There is another problem now.Imagine you have to get a log of your system to say later that who did what.